# Entity Framework Core Update-database specific migration gives no permission error

Tags: c#, .net-core, migration

I have created a migration earlier and applied to the database. I have had the table in the SQL Server database. Then I delete the table using SQL Server. So the table is not in the database anymore.

After that, I wanted to re-apply the same migrations using `dotnet ef database update AddScreens`. `AddScreens` is the name of the migration.

However, running this throws the following error:

> Cannot find the object "Screens" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions

I am trying to add `Screens` table to the SQL Server again using CLI. I have tried to create a new migration but this time it gave me a blank migration. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the table __MigrationHistory ?

Every Migration you apply is recorded inside this table. If you have inserted the table with update database eg. the record is inside there and Entity Framework does try to find the table.

You can also check at first for the Migrations:

```
Get-Migrations
```

If you would want to revert a recent migration

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration:"<name>"
```

is the way to go. I think currently your database schema and EF is missmatched.

You could manually restore the table and check if the database is ok again or re-create the whole schema (but this way you loese the data).

Sadly I do not know how to check with PMC the schema, by code it is:

```
if(context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true))
..
```